# Let $S$ be a set of $2009$ positive integer numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of $2009$ positive integer numbers. $S$ has the property that for any distinct $a, b, c\in S$ if $gcd(a, b)>1$, then at least $gcd(a, c)$ or $gcd(b, c)$ is also greater than $1$. Suppose that there is no group of $50$ elements in which every two of them are prime with each- other. Prove that there exist $40$ elements from $S$ such that every two of them have a common factor greater than $1$.

Can you give me any hint please? I don't know how to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: No, that's ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

There are at least two elements $x$ and $y$ in $S$ such that $gcd(x,y)>1$. Let $B$ be the maximal set with this property: $ \forall x,y \in B, gcd(x,y)>1 $. Suppose that $B=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$.

Now for $1\leq i\leq k$ define $ A_i:=\{x\in S | gcd(x,x_i)=1\} $.

First prove that for each i, $ |A_i|<49 $ (Use the fact that for every $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $S$, if $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $gcd(a,c)=1$ then $gcd(b,c)=1$), then notice that $B$ is maximal and show that $ S=(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_k )\cup B $.

Now if $k<40$, we can conclude that $ |S|<40*49+40=2000 $; a contradiction.